# Why is this mod_rewrite changing the visible URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Does anyone know why the following rule visibly changes the browser's address bar? I don't want it to.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (module)=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^(.+?)(\/[^\/]+)?$ $1/%1%2? [NE]
```

It should take a URL like

/module/video/item12345/?module=67890

and do an internal redirect to

/module/video/123456/module67890 (i.e. turn query string syntax into directory syntax)

The redirect happens, but the visible URL is swapped out.

Any thoughts? This is getting annoying... Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the htaccess located? Also you rewriterule doesn't seem to remove the `item` part in front of the number, which makes me suspect there are some other rewriterules in some other htaccess file. Please show us all you htaccess content, because the rules above should not cause a redirect. (also try clearing your browsercache)

Comment: Thanks, Gerben. I cannot post the full file here as it exceeds the char limit for SO comments. The file is located in /pruk. There are no other .htaccess files in play. There are 2 other rules beneath it (but removing these still causes the problem).

[EDIT] - I've put the file here: http://www.mitya.co.uk/htaccess.txt for you to view. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

After your comment, here's copy paste of your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

# ------ force trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L]

# ------ remove duplicate slashes
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ (.*)//+(.*)\  [NC]
RewriteRule .* %1/%2 [R=301,L]

# ------ site-specific redirect rules...
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (module)=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^(.+?)(\/[^\/]+)?$ $1/%1%2? [NE]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (ITEM_ENT_ID)=([^&]*)&(?:amp;)?.*(FILE_SERVICE_CONF_ID)=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^(.+?)(\/[^\/]+)?$ $1/%1%2/%3%4$2? [NE]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (ITEM_ENT_ID)=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^(.+?)(\/[^\/]+)?$ $1/%1%2$2? [NE]
```

There's only one redirect (= the only part that changes the URL) and it's here:

```
# ------ remove duplicate slashes
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ (.*)//+(.*)\  [NC]
RewriteRule .* %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

So my guess is that, even though this RewriteRule is validated only once, there's a redirect that is visible on the client's side.

Please tell me if I'm right.

### Two hints:

If you're not in a hosted environment (= if it's your own server and you can modify the virtual hosts, not only the `.htaccess` files), try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: Thanks, Oliver. However the problem occurred before I added the multiple-slashes fix, and occurs still if I remove it. Even if I reduce the file to JUST the modules rule, it still occurs. This is perverse, given that the rules further down (the bottom rule, for example) do NOT result in a visible change in URL, even though their structure is almost identical. The more I look into this, and the more it seems no one can solve it, the more I think it's a quirk of our server. We run the server, so I'll ask our server admins to look at the log.

Comment: "if I reduce the file to JUST the modules rule" => Okay... and without the Rewrite rules, there's no redirect *at all*? Are you *sure*? Did you try with multiple browsers, empty cache, try in private session to be sure there's nothing left when you quit the browser and so on? Each time you've added a rewrite rule? What if you turn Off rewrite rules (= just rename `.htaccess` to `.htaccess.sav`)?

Comment: "However the problem occurred before I added the multiple-slashes fix, and occurs still if I remove it." => This is very typical problem: you think that you've done nothing between those two modifications you have done something. Computer doesn't create new stuff by itself... I've done this kind of mistake many times ;) Try to find exactly **what else you've modified**.

Comment: I understand your whole "somehow it's your fault, not the computer's" argument. However there are no other .htaccess files, and even when I reduce the .htaccess file down to this rule alone - no others - and clear cache etc etc. And yes, tried in multiple browsers. It always, always makes the redirect visible. What I have just noticed is that, if I DON'T reference the QS args in my replacement, it doesn't do this.